# Why is it showing "Page not found" when I confirm my email address?

Tags: bug, accounts

Why does it show "page not found (404)" when I click on <kbd>Confirm my email address</kbd> and also display a message saying *Your email is verified*?

Here is an image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Because someone made a boo boo, of course :)

Comment: What is the URL (or URL format) you're taken to when this happens?